# Debian PHP 5.4.27 vs Ubuntu PHP 5.4.16

Tags: php, ubuntu, debian

Well, I'm transferring a little web server from one computer to other, on the 'other' computer I cannot a more updated version of PHP,

I just have to add my files through ssh and that's all, when I load my webpage it says explicitly:

The error is showing on a Debian with PHP 5.4.27 squeeze, the webserver comes from an Ubuntu with PHP 5.4.16 oneiric

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ~directory~ on line 38
```

This is the line 38.

```
$VALUE=$DB->query("a nice sentence")->fetch()[0];
```

So, i was pretty surprised because PDO was accepted since PHP 5.1, so, i look deeper and i found the possible error, you can't simply do `->fetch()[0]`, you must separate it in order to be "processed",

However, I have transport this server with this information before, so i really don't know if it's something on the configuration of PHP or maybe the version by itself 5.4.X? You guys know any hint? As I said, i can't just install other updated version of PHP5, what do you recommend?

Have a nice night.

**Edit: updated to the issue on the PHP 5.4 now**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the error was solved by **JUST** changing the first issue line (the other hundreds of codes that had that wasn't necessary to change, what i believe to be a little weird).

```
$VALUE = $DB->query("a nice sentence")->fetch()->offset(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems triggered by the array dereferencing. This was added in PHP 5.4.. Not sure how you made that work in 5.3.6

https://www.php.net/language.types.array.php

To workaround you could try

```
$VALUE = $DB->query("a nice sentence")->fetch();
echo $VALUE[0];
```

Comment: That "workaround" is precisely what i'm trying to avoid, however, i managed to install in the Debian the version 5.4.27, however, this is not solving my problem, probably apache2 is still using the 5.3.3 engine, do you know how to manage this?

Comment: Nevermind, is not that, i just checked and i do have installed php 5.4.27 and i have no updates on the error.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Version on my ubuntu (where it works):

```
PHP Version 5.4.16
```

PHP Version on the Debian (where it does not work):

```
PHP Version 5.4.27-1~dotdeb.0
```

This version number was extracted by using phpinfo(); on the index page.